# Is «Does anyone have access to this paper?» a valid question?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, references

Are the questions of the type «Does anyone have access to this paper?» valid at CV?

Comment: I'd regard it as off-topic; it's not a question on statistics / machine learning but on access to papers. If you were to ask on chat that might be okay (e.g. if you wanted to know if someone could check some detail in a paper for you; asking to be supplied with a paper you didn't have legitimate access to would not be okay there either).

Comment: Also, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sci-Hub.

Comment: @amoeba many thanks.

Comment: @Glen_b I got it. Thanks

Comment: To clarify in relation to the "asking to be supplied" part, I'm not discussing there my feelings about the merits of many publishing houses (I see serious problems there and at times harbour a degree of moral outrage at some of what happens but this isn't the forum for that) nor even directly about copyright (we - especially the mods - can't be in the position of being gatekeepers for that), but more about the impact on the nature of the chat. Asking would place people in the position of feeling they have to respond in some way, and that could badly impact the social nature of the chat.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is off-topic because it isn't about [statistics, machine learning, etc](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic); but having access to a given reference. It would also be kind of a private question which is of low interest to the community.

Glen_b provides more advice within a comment:

> I'd regard it as off-topic; it's not a question on statistics / machine learning but on access to papers. If you were to ask on chat that might be okay (e.g. if you wanted to know if someone could check some detail in a paper for you; asking to be supplied with a paper you didn't have legitimate access to would not be okay there either).